# Getting selected item in ListView without selecting an Item on UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm working on a WPF application where I've made a ListView on UI which is two-way binding enabled. This WPF application is being developed for a windows 10 based smartphone. So whenever a user taps an item in the list whose data source is data-binded to back data collection, I've to do some operation for that item in code behind.
Now the problem is, I always receive a null object from the below function whenever the user taps on the item.

```
CartItem selectedItem = (CartItem)lv_CartItems.SelectedItem;
```

I only get a filled item object when the user actually selects an item by clicking on ListViewItem rather than tapping on it.
I want to get the selected item when the user taps on it. Is there any workaround available in WPF this problem? I've stuck here

My ListViewItem template looks like this.

```
            <ListView Name="lv_CartItems"  Loaded="lv_CartItems_Loaded" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                      Width="250" Height="230"  SelectionMode="Single" 
                      >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Viewbox>
                            <Grid Width="230" Height="110" >

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".1*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1"
                                   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="3" >
                                </Border>

                                
                                <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" >
                                    <Image Name="img_ItemImage" 
                                           Source="{Binding Image, Mode=TwoWay }" 
                                           Width="20" Height=" 25" />
                                </Viewbox>

                                <Viewbox Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                                    <TextBlock Name="lbl_ItemName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="180" Foreground="Gray"
                                               Text="{Binding Name , Mode=TwoWay }"  >
                                        
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Viewbox>

                                <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                                    <TextBlock  Foreground="Gray" >Qty:</TextBlock>
                                </Viewbox>

                                <Viewbox Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                        <Button  Name="btn_Minus" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Tag="{Binding SKU_No,Mode=TwoWay}" Padding="0"  Width="12"   
                                             Resources="{StaticResource cartitembutton}" Click="btn_Minus_Click" >
                                            <Image Source="/Resources\Icons\minus.png" ></Image>
                                        </Button>

                                        <Border BorderThickness="1" Margin="2,0" Width="13" CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="LightGray"   >
                                            <TextBlock Name="lbl_Quantity"  FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                   Text="{Binding Quantity , Mode=TwoWay }"  >
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </Border>

                                        <Button Name="btn_Increment"  FontWeight="ExtraBold"  Width="12"
                                             Resources="{StaticResource cartitembutton}" Tag="{Binding SKU_No,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                            Padding="0" 
                                            Click="btn_Increment_Click">
                                            <Image Source="/Resources\Icons\union_10.png" ></Image>
                                        </Button>

                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Viewbox>

                                <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,0" 
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  >
                                    <TextBlock Name="lbl_Price"  FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                                Text="{Binding Price , Mode=TwoWay}" ></TextBlock>
                                </Viewbox>

                                <Viewbox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                                     VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0"  >
                                    <TextBlock Name="lbl_Appearence" 
                                               Text="{Binding Appearance , Mode=TwoWay }" 
                                               TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Gray" Width="210" >
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Viewbox>

                                <Viewbox Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2,2"
                                    >
                                    <Button Name="btn_DeleteItem" 
                                            Click="btn_DeleteItem_Click" 
                                            Resources="{StaticResource cartitembutton}" >
                                        <Image Source="/Resources/Icons/delete.png"  ></Image>
                                    </Button>
                                </Viewbox>

                            </Grid>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            
            
            </ListView>
```

This is how a listVeiw looks like.

[image]

Comment: try to use some other events, focus or select if available.

Comment: Where's the listview markup?  Have you set IsManipulationEnabled ="true"

Comment: By "tap on the item", do you mean pressing one of the buttons on the item (like "+", "-" or "x"), or do you mean something else? What are you trying to do in the method where the error is happening?

Comment: @KeithStein By "tag on the item" mean pressing one of the buttons on the item ( like "+" or "-" ).

Comment: @Andy I've updated the Code in question.

Comment: Set IsManipulationEnabled ="true"

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually want the selected item, you want to know which item contained the button that was clicked- whether that item is selected or not.

You *can* do this with events, but the more "correct" way to do it in WPF is with [commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview).

Commands are a pattern which separate the logic of an action (e.g. deleting an item) from the visual component that triggers the action (e.g. the button the user clicks). A command includes a parameter, which you can use to specify which item the command is being executed on. There are a couple different types on commands in WPF, but I'll be explaining using [RoutedCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.routedcommand).

In your case you'd first declare your command(s) in your `Window`:

```
public static readonly RoutedCommand DeleteItemCommand =
    new RoutedCommand("DeleteItem", typeof(MainWindow));

private void OnCanExecuteDeleteItem(object sender , CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = e.Parameter != null;
}

private void OnExecuteDeleteItem(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SomeType item = (SomeType)e.Parameter;

    //Actually delete the item
}
```

And you'd add a `CommandBinding` to your `Window` which links the command to the methods which handle it:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="local:MainWindow.DeleteItemCommand" CanExecute="OnCanExecuteDeleteItem" Executed="OnExecuteDeleteItem"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

And finally, to link your delete `Button` to the command:

```
<Button Name="btn_DeleteItem" Resources="{StaticResource cartitembutton}" Command="local:MainWindow.DeleteItemCommand" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
    <Image Source="/Resources/Icons/delete.png"/>
</Button>
```

`CommandParameter="{Binding}"` works because your `Button` is inside a `DataTemplate`, so its `DataContext` will be the item that is being displayed. This lets you check `e.Parameter` in your routed event methods to see which item is being interacted with.

Comment: @ammar-the-trainer  If this answer ended up solving your problem, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).